# X-infinite, consider zariski topology.

Tags: general-topology

Which subsets are closed in X with zariski topology? Is the set of integers closed or open in zariski topology on R? 
What kind of Union of open intervals is open in zariski topology and Euclidean topology?

Comment: What is your definition of the Zariski topology? (I'm aware of two different ones, although one is less common).

Comment: Are you only interested in the case when $X = \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

Finite unions of zero sets of polynomials are closed in the Zariski topology.

In the real line, each non-zero polynomial has finitely many points in the zero set, so only finite unions of points (and the whole space itself) are closed.

This should be enough to answer your two questions. Let me know if you get stuck.